# I want to remove "localhost" from [string[]]$Servers

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I want to remove `localhost` from the string but the following commands are not working. Any ideas why not?

option 1:

```
[string[]]$Servers = '"localhost","tbhserver"'
$Servers = $servers | Where-Object {$_ -ne "localhost"}
```

option 2:

```
[string[]]$Servers = '"localhost","tbhserver"'
$Servers 
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$servers = $servers
$servers.Remove("localhost")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're only assigning one string, '"localhost","tbhserver"', to $Servers, rather than a list of two.

Does this work?

```
$Servers = @("localhost", "tbhserver")
$Servers = $Servers | Where-Object {$_ -ne "localhost"}
```

I'm not at a Windows machine right now, so I cannot test this.

Comment: Yeap makes total sense now.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the -ne parameter:

```
$servers = 'localhost', 'tbhserver'
$servers = $servers -ne 'localhost'
```